# Shows that some surds cannot satisfy this equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $\alpha=\sqrt[3] 2$, $\beta=\sqrt[4] 5$.

I would hope to show that $c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2=0$ is impossible, where $c_i$ are elements in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$, and $c_2$ is nonzero.
How do I go about proving it?
Thanks!

What I tried is the quadratic formula, but got stuck since the square root operation does not "remain in the field".

Comment: You are asking whether the field $\Bbb Q(\alpha,\beta)$ is indeed cubic over $\Bbb Q(\beta)$, with one possible basis being $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$. This is true, and there are various ways of showing it.

Comment: @Lubin thanks, is there a way by showing degrees 1 and 2 are not possible? I can show degree 1 is not possible, but stuck with degree 2 (the question above)

Comment: No, the fact is that there is no expression $c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2=0$ of the type you specify except with all the $c$’s equal to zero. I intentionally did not offer a proof, in the hope that someone else would give one.